# Weblogic 11g JDBC driver taking long

Tags: java, jdbc, weblogic, weblogic11g

I have 2 identical Weblogic 11g servers set up on the same physical server and drive. They are practically clones of each other but they were both installed from the wizard. They hit the same database using the same jtds JDBC driver. They run the same application.

One however takes much longer in performing stored procedures in the application than the other.

Using an application monitoring App I seem to have narrowed the time difference in the thread named "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket:readPacket:841" which takes around a full second more to perform on the slower WL instance than the other, and in the stored procedure that thread is called around 50 times which results in the slower WL server taking over a min to run the same process that takes the faster WL server only a few seconds to run.

What other setting could I be missing?

Comment: JTDS is opensource jdbc driver implementation for MS SQL Server, its not (and never was) fully compatible and has no support. Try to use offical jdbc driver from Microsoft first http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx .Also described problems can happen due to different network configuration or working firewall/antivirus software. This not related to Weblogic itself.

Comment: Any further information? Let's say the JDBC connection pools monitoring results on both servers. Were you calling it concurrently?

Comment: I tried running each WL instance separately on the same physical server, under the same WL and JAVA home directory structures, using the same exact JDBC driver file, with the same exact settings in the startWebLogic.cmd, commEnv.cmd and all other config files except of course for the port and domain folder location. Even when running separately one takes considerably longer to run the same exact procedure than the other one.